# Restrict Magento customer to Stores

Tags: magento, store, restrict, associate

I am using a Magento website with over 10 stores. These stores are managed by different companies. However, if a customer created an account in Store(View) 1, he can also log in on StoreView 2. Is their a way to restrict this and make sure he can only login to the Store he was created in?

I know it is possible to restrict account sharing on a website level, but I need Store level.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting `Use SID on Frontend` to **No**? Look in *Admin > System > Configuration > General > Web > Session Validation Settings*. Note that Magento only supports account limitations to `per Website`, or `Global`, not `per Store`.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Magento only supports limiting user accounts on a `Global` or `per Website` basis,  *not* `per Store`.

Those settings are at *Admin > System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Account Sharing Options*.

To try to answer your question, you *can* force the user to logout between stores/websites. Look in *Admin > System > Configuration > General > Web > Session Validation Settings* and set `Use SID on Frontend` to **No**.

If the limitations **have** to be `per Store`, then you will need a module to introduce that.